# Why do black lines appear at the bottom of older anime?

Tags: anime-production, transformers

I've noticed in older anime (70's-early 90's), before each cut a black line on the bottom (or white scratches on top) would appear in the picture, and I've noticed this in tokusatsu as well. Does anyone know what this is?
I've mainly seen anime and toku from Toei, so I'm not sure if this was a thing unique to them.

[image: From Transformers: The Headmasters]

[image: From Jetman]

[image: From Transformers: Zone]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related specifically to anime because I think old Western movies/recording also have this kind of phenomenon. But I'll let the community to decide.

Comment: If they only appear for a fraction of a second between scenes then it could be tape used to splice the film together.

Comment: Perhaps some info in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_transition

Comment: It looks like an artifact of the show having been recorded on video cassette and then transferred onto another medium - it can happen if there's something wrong with the read heads, or if the tape inside the cassette has degraded a little (which can often happen both due to time and if the tape has been used many times).